# python: from arduino serial port to csv file, why the data format is strange?

Tags: python, arduino, export-to-csv

*/I apologize for my limited level of English which may cause the question not that clear./*
I'm now using python to write the data which was sent from the arduino into a csv file, I want around 200 data in a group, one group for one row, every data separately in different colums. The data from my aruino is in the format: number+, (for example: 123,144,135,....) but in csv file, the number had been separated into different colums (1,2,3 in different colums instead of 123 in one colum), and when open the file by writing note, the data looks like "1,2,3","1,4,4",.....

I tried different delimeters like \t, space... \t looks fine when I viewed the file by excel but still didn't work in writing pad (a tab between every two numbers).
I also tried to delete the "," in arduino code but it doesn't help as well.
In the writerows() function, I tried data, str(data) and str(data)+"," ,not much difference. 
I even changed the delimeter setting of my laptop from "," to "\t" but dosen't help.

The arduino part:

```
  Serial.print(value);
  Serial.print(",");
```

The python part:

```
   while True:
    try:
        ser_bytes = ser.readline()
        decoded_bytes = ser_bytes.decode('utf-8')
        print(decoded_bytes)
        #decoded_bytes = decoded_bytes.strip('|')

        with open("test_data.csv","a",newline="") as f:
            writer = csv.writer(f,delimiter=",")
            writer.writerows([str(decoded_bytes),])
```

I searched a lot about the csv format but I still can't get the point why the code doesn't work. 
Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're right, I think I didn't totally get what your question is, but here are some ideas. To get correct csv output, you have to change your code to something like this:

```
while True:
try:
    ser_bytes = ser.readline()
    // the following line splits the line you got from your arduino into an array
    decoded_bytes = ser_bytes.split(",");
    print(decoded_bytes)

    with open("test_data.csv","a") as f:
        writer = csv.writer(f,delimiter=",")
        writer.writerow(decoded_bytes)
```

Like this you should get correct csv output and every line you get from the arduino is written to a line in the file.

Some additional thoughts: Since you're a getting a csv style line from your arduino already you could write that to a file directly, without splitting and using the csv writer. That's actually a little overkill, but it probably doesn't matter that much ;)